# Issue : EF Core 3.1 gives incorrect value for Tables column which is updated using Ado.Net

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, ef-core-3.1

I have a situation in my code where first when i update a table column using Ado.net and then when i use EFCore 3.1 to fetch the particular table's data using DbContext.Entities, i dont get the correct value.
Below is the code which i am using:

```
var sqlCommandText = "Update testTable set Value = 10"; 
var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection();
using var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText); 
sqlConnection.Open();
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

Below is the Model and DbContext to be used by EF Core-

```
   public class TestTable
   {
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public int Value {get;set;}
   }

   public class TestDbContext : DbContext 
  {
      public TestDbContext() : base("connectionString")
      {
      }
     
      public DbSet<TestTable> TestTable {get;set;}

  }
```

Now when i use the below code to get the TestTable data from Context, i dont see the newly updated value for 'Value' column.

```
  var columnsValue = _dbContext.TestTable.ToList()[0].Value;
```

**This value is coming as 0 whereas it should be 10 as per Ado.Net code.** 
Pls Let me know what is the issue here.

Comment: Please show the code that brings both parts together. If the context already had the objects in its cache then a second query won't overwrite the values in cache.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that your code sets Value=10.

Try this

```
var sqlCommandText = "Update testTable set Value = 10;"; 
 var result= _dbContext.DataBase.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCommandText);
if(result==0) ...error
```

The dbContext is not getting refreshed automatically after executeSql. You have to reload the entry that was changed. And try to use FirstOrDefault instead of list:

```
var item= _dbContext.TestTable.FirstOrDefault();
if(item!=null)
{
_dbContext.Entry(item).Reload();
var columnsValue=item.Value;
}
```

Comment: Sql query does change the value in the db. I checked in the Db and the value was udpated.